# how to explode a url string?

Tags: php

code:

```
<?php
    include('conn.php');
    $student_id = $_SESSION['student_id'];
    $college_name = $_GET['college_name'];
    $college_name22 = explode('(', $college_name);
    if(preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $college_name, $match))
    {
        $match[1] = lcfirst($match[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        $match[1] = 'All';
    }
```

?>

If url having string like

```
cstest/view.php?college_name=Agra%20Public%20Institute%20of%20Technology%20&%20Computer%20Education,%20Artoni%20(Pharmacy)
```

and I want to explode the following string i.e.

```
Agra%20Public%20Institute%20of%20Technology%20&%20Computer%20Education,%20Artoni%20(Pharmacy)
```

when I echo $college_name it display only (Agra Public Institute of Technology) not full name i.e (Agra Public Institute of Technology & Computer Education, Artoni) and $match[1] contain (pharmacy) which is not showing when I print $match[1] it show 'All'. So, how can I fix this problem ?

Thank You

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)` looks like what? For starters, it's not going to have URL encoded strings in it. And if you're accessing a URL with `,` and `(` in it, your browser has problems, they would also be encoded as %2C and %28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` has a special meaning in URL. the value of `$_GET['college_name']` is exactly "Agra%20Public%20Institute%20of%20Technology%20". The `&` marks the start of a new parameter.

If the ampersand is properly escaped as `%26` you will have a much easier time.

You could try inserting a `var_dump($_GET)` and see what the data is that you are actually working with.

Comment: I am using var_dump like $college_name = var_dump($_GET['college_name']); and it give the following result like string(36) "Agra Public Institute of Technology

Comment: var_dump the whole array, `$_GET`. See what else you have in there.